# allauth/dj_rest_auth - How come Google OAuth2 works without backend server knowing client_id, client_secret

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, django-allauth

I tried to implement **Google OAuth2** authentication in this project. Backend server runs **Django** and **DRF**. To login using rest API, I use `dj_rest_auth` library.

This is roughly how it works:

1. front-end generates auth url like `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth/i...`
2. user authenticates
3. frontend receives `access_token`
4. `access_token` is being sent to API to `{{API_URL}}auth/google/`
5. backend fetches profile information using this token and saves user

I needed to register `SocialApp` with Google provider but it looks like it is only used for profile fetching. In fact I just used `client_id="xxx"` and no `client_secret`.

I would expect that the `access_token` is somehow verified using the `client_id` and `client_secret` but obviously it works without them.

Is that safe?

Comment: Is it clientcredentials? then presenting `access_token` is enough to verify the client.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an `access token` You don't really need to pass your `client_id` and `client_secret` anymore. Either it's `JWT` or `reference` type token, the `identity server` is going to validate your client by parsing `JWT` or matching the `reference token` that mapped with a registered client.

You need to pass in those values when you request your `identity provider` an access token in the HTTP header as below.

```
Authorization: Basic Base64Encode(clientId:clientSecret)
```

Please check out [client password section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1) here in RFC 6749 and [Basic authentication scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2) in RFC 2617 for more details about constructing the `Basic` value.

> I would expect that the access_token is somehow verified using the client_id and client_secret but obviously it works without them. Is that safe?

Yes it is, because the `identity provider` can fully trust the client `the access token` represents. That's the beauty of [client credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) flow

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the access_token is "valid" but theoretically, an attacker can use access_token that have been used to login on a different website.